# A ResetBindings on a BindingSource of a Grid also resets ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, enums

I have a DataGridView with a BindingSource of products. This products have an enum (Producer).

For the most text fields (to edit the product) below the DataGridView I have a method RefreshProduct which does a ResetBindings in the end to refresh the DataGridView. There is a ComboBox (cboProducer), too.

If I run over the _orderBs.ResetBindings(false) it will reset my cboProducer outside the DataGridView, too. Could you please help me to avoid this?

Here follows some code; maybe it is then better to understand.

```
public partial class SelectProducts : UserControl
    {
        private AutoCompleteStringCollection _productCollection;
        private ProductBL _productBL;
        private OrderBL _orderBL;
        private SortableBindingList<ProductBE> _listProducts;
        private ProductBE _selectedProduct;
        private OrderBE _order;
        BindingSource _orderBs = new BindingSource();

        public SelectProducts()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (_productBL == null)
                _productBL = new ProductBL();

            if (_orderBL == null)
                _orderBL = new OrderBL();

            if (_productCollection == null)
                _productCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

            if (_order == null)
                _order = new OrderBE();

            if (_listProducts == null)
            {
                _listProducts = _order.ProductList;
                _orderBs.DataSource = _order;
                grdOrder.DataSource = _orderBs;
                grdOrder.DataMember = "ProductList";
            }
        }

        private void cmdGetProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProductBE product = _productBL.Load(txtProductNumber.Text);
            _listProducts.Add(product);

            _orderBs.ResetBindings(false);
        }

        private void grdOrder_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (grdOrder.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                _selectedProduct = (ProductBE)((DataGridView)(sender)).CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
                if (_selectedProduct != null)
                {
                    txtArticleNumber.Text = _selectedProduct.Article;
                    txtPrice.Text = _selectedProduct.Price.ToString("C");
                    txtProducerNew.Text = _selectedProduct.ProducerText;
                    cboProducer.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Producer));
                    cboProducer.SelectedItem = _selectedProduct.Producer;
                }
            }
        }

        private void txtProducerNew_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string property = CommonMethods.GetPropertyName(() => new ProductBE().ProducerText);
            RefreshProduct(((TextBoxBase)sender).Text, property);
        }

        private void RefreshProduct(object value, string property)
        {
            if (_selectedProduct != null)
            {
                double valueOfDouble;
                if (double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out valueOfDouble))
                {
                    value = valueOfDouble;
                }

                Type type = _selectedProduct.GetType();
                PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(property);

                if (info.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
                {
                    value = Enum.Parse(info.PropertyType, value.ToString()); 
                }

                try
                {
                    Convert.ChangeType(value, info.PropertyType, new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
                    info.SetValue(_selectedProduct, value, null);
                }                    
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new WrongFormatException("\"" + value.ToString() + "\" is not a valid value.", ex);
                }


                var produktFromList = _listProducts.Single(p => p.Position == _selectedProduct.Position);
                info.SetValue(produktFromList, value, null);

                _orderBs.ResetBindings(false);
            }
        }

        private void cboProducer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedIndex = ((ComboBox)(sender)).SelectedIndex;
            switch ((Producer)selectedIndex)
            {
                case Producer.ABC:
                    txtProducerNew.Text = Constants.ABC;
                    break;
                case Producer.DEF:
                    txtProducerNew.Text = Constants.DEF;
                    break;
                case Producer.GHI:
                    txtProducerNew.Text = Constants.GHI;
                    break;
                case Producer.Another:
                    txtProducerNew.Text = String.Empty;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            string property = CommonMethods.GetPropertyName(() => new ProductBE().Producer);
            RefreshProduct(selectedIndex, property);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it! 
After the ResetBindings the grdOrder_SelectionChanged-Event was raised. And after the _selectedProduct was null (I do not know why yet...) the DataSource of the cboProducer was setted again.

So the solution is to set the DataSource of the cboProducer in the constructor.

Thanks for reading.